# Help With Geometric Interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{z}$, where $\mathbf{y}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{z} = 0$. Also, let $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ be the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{x}$.

I am trying to wrap my head around the geometric interpretation of the following linear mapping $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ but have not been successful:

$$
\mathbf{A} = 2\Vert \mathbf{y} \Vert^2 \mathbf{I} - \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^2 \left( \mathbf{I} - \hat{\mathbf{x}} \hat{\mathbf{x}}^\mathrm{T} \right)
$$

I have messed around with writing this every which way I can think of, but nothing stands out. Since $\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert ^2 = \Vert \mathbf{y} \Vert ^2 + \Vert \mathbf{z} \Vert ^2$ and $\left( \mathbf{I} - \hat{\mathbf{x}} \hat{\mathbf{x}}^\mathrm{T} \right)$ is the projection onto the plane with normal vector $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$, it seems like the above should have an intuitive geometric interpretation. Any help sussing one out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a solution, but consider analysing its effect on $\lambda y + \mu z + \nu w$, where $w$ is perpendicular to $y,z$.

Comment: $$A=\underbrace{(\Vert y\Vert^2-\Vert z\Vert^2)I}_{\text{scaling up/down}}+\underbrace{x\cdot x^t}_{\text{projection?}}$$

Comment: Given any vector $\mathbf v$, the mapping $\mathbf A$ simply scales the $\hat{\mathbf x}$ component of a vector by the factor $2\|\mathbf y\|^2$ and scales the component orthogonal to $\hat{\mathbf x}$ by another factor $\|\mathbf y\|^2-\|\mathbf z\|^2$. In other words, with respect to an orthonormal basis whose first basis vector is $\hat{\mathbf x}$, the matrix representation of $\mathbf A$ is just $\operatorname{diag}(2\|\mathbf y\|^2,\,\|\mathbf y\|^2-\|\mathbf z\|^2,\,\|\mathbf y\|^2-\|\mathbf z\|^2)$. There is nothing remarkable here.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}A&=(\Vert y\Vert^2+\Vert y\Vert^2-\Vert x\Vert^2)I-x\cdot x^t\\&=(\Vert y\Vert^2-\Vert z\Vert^2)I-x\cdot x^t\\Aw&=aw-bx\end{align}$$

This transformation adds any vector w with a scaled version of x.

Comment: $Aw=|\Vert x\Vert^2(\cos({2\theta})\cdot w-\underbrace{\hat x\cdot \hat x^t\cdot w}_{w_x}),\angle \theta=\angle(y,x)$

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the $2\theta$ relationship because it reminded me of $\cos^2 -\sin^2$. Not sure what to make of it.